# Hide all li elements and show the first 2 and toggle them by button

Tags: jquery

Assume I have

```
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

I want jQuery code to hide all `<li>` then show the fist and the second one
then `append()` an additional `<li>more</li>` that is used to toggle the
hidden li.

Comment: you lost me on 'append ... to toggle'

Comment: @xtofl - wants an additional `li` containing the word `more` that is used to toggle the visibility of the 2 hidden list elements.  At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: @tvanfosson your r great

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this should do it ..

```
// hide all li and then show the first two
$('ul li').hide().filter(':lt(2)').show(); 

// append a li with text more that on click will show the rest
$('ul').append('<li>more</li>').find('li:last').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(':gt(1)').toggle();
});
```

**demo :**

```js
$('ul li').hide().filter(':lt(2)').show();
$('ul').append('<li>more</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(':gt(1)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Update to add changing text from more to less ..

```
$('ul li')
    .hide()
    .filter(':lt(2)')
    .show();

$('ul')
    .append('<li><span>more</span><span class="less">less</span></li>')
    .find('li:last')
    .click(function(){
        $(this)
            .siblings(':gt(1)')
            .toggle()
            .end()
            .find('span')
            .toggle();
    });
```

needs a css rule of `.less{display:none}`

**demo :**

```js
$('ul li')
  .hide()
  .filter(':lt(2)')
  .show();

$('ul')
  .append('<li><span>more</span><span class="less">less</span></li>')
  .find('li:last')
  .click(function() {
    $(this)
      .siblings(':gt(1)')
      .toggle()
      .end()
      .find('span')
      .toggle();
  });
```

```css
.less {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does it hide them when the `more` link is clicked again?

Comment: @tvanfosson, it doesn't ... interpreted the toggle part to just show.. looking into it..

Comment: @tvanfosson, fixed but it starts becoming a mess to maintain :)

Comment: 8=========> its dont hide agian

Comment: how i can make more be less and add active and non-active class

Answer (score 5):

Is this something like you're looking for?

```
 $('li').hide()
        .slice(0,1)
        .addClass('fixed')
        .show();
 $('<li class="toggle">more</li>')
        .appendTo('ul')
        .click( function() {
             $('li:not(.toggle,.fixed)').toggle();
         });
```

Comment: @moustafa - I was just using your html.