# Remove list item and add them to and unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working with the following the amount of link's is not always the same

```
 <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
    <li>link 5</li>
    <li>link 6</li>
    <li>link 7</li>
    <li>link 8</li>
 </ul>
```

Now when I'm having more than 5 links I need to remove all the items more than the 5 link and add them to a unordered list

so i need to get the following

```
 <ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
    <li>link 4</li>
    <li>link 5</li>
    <li>more+</li>
    <ul>
        <li>link 6</li>
        <li>link 7</li>
        <li>link 8</li>
    </ul>
 </ul>
```

I tried the following only i dit not know how to add the sliced list items to a var

```
$('li').slice(5).remove();
$( "ul" ).append( "<li>More +</li> <ul><li>link 6</li></ul>" );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ul list expand - less and more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050313/ul-list-expand-less-and-more)

Comment: I'm not willing to hide the other items i'm willing to add them to an unordered list <li style="display: none;">link 5</li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var slicer=$('li').size()-5;
var removedItems=$('li').slice("-"+slicer); 
$( "ul" ).append( "<li>More +<ul id='moreItems'></ul></li>" );
$( "#moreItems" ).append( removedItems );
```

The `slicer` var get the exceeding elements of the ul and the `removedItems` take the jQuery elements starting from the slicer variable.

Than you can append them to the new list.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/UqqJJ/

Comment: Note this will lead to having invalid HTML (due to ` ul` as a direct child of a `ul`) which may result in other rendering errors on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove the slice or else it deletes it from the dom.  First make the slice selection as you did and assign it to a variable, then append that variable to the UL.  Then you can remove whatever you want from the DOM.

```
var myItemsGreaterThan5 = $('li').slice(5);
$( "ul" ).append( "<li>More +</li>" + myItemsGreaterThan5 );
myItemsGreaterThan5.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $additionalLi = $('li').slice(5).remove();
if ($additionalLi.length) {
    $('<li />', { 'class': 'expand' }).text('More +')
        .append($additionalLi.wrap('<ul></ul>').parent())
        .appendTo('ul');
}

$('ul').on('click', 'li.expand', function() {
    $('ul', this).toggle();
});
```

You'll also need to set the child `ul` elements to start hidden:

```
ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Gra/)

Comment: you are making separated <ul><li></li></ul> i need 1 with all the "more" li

Comment: That's correct. You cannot have a `ul` as a child of `ul` - only `li` elements. Therefore a child `ul` must be inside an `li` to maintain page validity.